# MySQL/PHP - Database User Login Conversion

Tags: php, mysql, md5, salt, sha256

I have a vBulletin Database that I'm trying to switch users to a custom system, I've converted the usernames, and the passwords, I then converted the double MD5'd passwords to SHA256, but I'm left with one issue, which is the salt.

What would be the easiest way to either convert the old vBulletin salt, or to check to see if the password is correct, and then generate a new salt for the first time they login?

Checking script:

```
$vbconvert = md5(md5($_POST["password"]));
$check_password = hash('sha256', $vbconvert . $row['salt']); 
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
{ 
      $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
} 

if($check_password === $row['password']) 
{ 

      $login_ok = true; 
}
```

In short, what is the easiest way to either convert or create a new salt?

Comment: I would leave the "double md5'd" passwords to start with and then create a new DB column that keeps track of whether the user has an updated (SHA256) password. If they do not, then they are required to do a password reset on login which updates both the password and salt. That way, your users are still able to login, and you don't have to worry about reverse-engineering salts and hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about the PHP function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), it is the recommended way to hash passwords. It automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt for each password and includes it in the resulting 60-character string.

```
$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
```

The example above is a possible result of password_hash(), have a look at the part `$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veu`, this is the generated salt and it will be used by the function password_verify() to check the password.

You won't have to worry about the salt anymore, no additional database field is necessary, just store the hash and you are fine!

The easiest way to migrate your passwords, is to wait for the user to login the next time. When he enters the password, you can check if the hash is already migrated, then check with password_verify(). If it is not yet migrated then check it with your old vBulletin code, if the password is correct then use password_hash() to generate a new hash and store it.